# how to write to Test or Debug tab of Visual Studio with xUnit

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit

I have this code:

```
private readonly ITestOutputHelper _output;

public Test(ITestOutputHelper output)
{
    _output = output;
}

[Fact]
public void Test1()
{
    _output.WriteLine("TEST OUTPUT");
}
```

but I'm not sure why output (`TEST OUTPUT`) isn't logged anywhere

Test, is of course passing.

I'm using .NET Core 2.1

Comment: This code should work. What are you using to run the tests?

Comment: @Euphoric VS Test Explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the VS Test Explorer, select this test. In the details pane, click "Open additional output for this result". This should open new window with test's output.

[image]

Comment: works fine, thanks, but is it possible to see this output during test execution, not only after?

Comment: @Joelty Only thing I can recommend for that is to use different test runner. I know ReSharper's VS test runner displays the test's output as it runs.

Comment: oh :/ it hurts, thanks because I have a lot of tests already written in xUnit :( :P

Comment: @Joelty ReSharper's test runner is test-framework agnostic. It works with MSTest, nUnit, xUnit, etc.. But it is paid plugin. It has replacement for Visual Studio's test runner, not for testing framework.